# Creating multiples of the same DOM Element Image

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a new Developer and am working on a Tic Tac Toe SPA. I have a working game, but I want to customize the game tokens. I have tried creating a DOM element a few different ways, which were all successful.  Here is the problem:

Every time I go to make a second move for a player, the DOM image disappears and reappears in the new square selected. Obviously this is not the desired action.  Is there something I don't know about creating a DOM element.  I have googled this and read countless articles and watched countless videos.

```js
const stark = document.createElement('img')
  stark.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/d70XlET.png'
  stark.height = 80
  stark.width = 80

const lanister = document.createElement('img')
  lanister.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/d70XlET.png'
  lanister.height = 80
  lanister.width = 80

const play = (event) => {
  if (gameOver === false) {
    if (event.target.innerHTML === '') {
      $('#' + event.target.id).append(turn)
    }
  }
}
```

'turn' is a variable that works with a toggle function to switch between players and stores whichever players turn it is(i.e. 'stark')

I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the direction of a resource where I could learn more about this.

```js
const player1 = stark
const player2 = lanister

let turn = player1
let prevTurn = player2

const togglePrevTurn = () => {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (prevTurn === player1) {
      prevTurn = player2
    } else {
      prevTurn = player1
    }
  }
}

const toggleTurn = () => {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turn === player1) {
      turn = player2
    } else {
      turn = player1
    }
    $('#message').text(turn + " 's turn")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code for where `turn` gets assigned? (is `turn` really a function, it doesn't look like it?)

Comment: Sorry you were correct. It is not a function.  I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use Javascript's `appendChild` or jQuery's `append`, when you pass it an element, that element gets *removed* from its previous location in the DOM (if it's in the DOM), and *then* gets inserted at the new position. It sounds like what you need to do is explicitly create a new element each time, which you might do with `cloneNode()`.

Also, probably best to name your variables precisely - if `turn` is an image, name it to make it clear that it's an image, perhaps `currentPlayerImage`.

In addition, because you already have a reference to the `event.target`, there's no need to reselect it with `$('#' + event.target.id)` - just select `event.target`:

```
const play = (event) => {
  if (gameOver === false) {
    if (event.target.innerHTML === '') {
      $(event.target).append(currentPlayerImage.cloneNode());
    }
  }
}
```